# Is there a way to call a global function within a class that has a method whose name is the same as the global function?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

The code below gives an error because it tries to call the method of the class rather than a global function:

```
func a(i: Int) -> Int {
    return i + 10
}

class B {
    func a(s: String) -> String {
       return s + "bbb"
    }

    func b() {
        print(a(100))   
        // Error (Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'String')
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad for the answer, but my god, do you really want to do this?

Comment: I have a util file that includes some global useful functions that supposed to be used in a whole project like for debugging, logging and error handling and so on, as with MACRO in Obj-C.
I know it may be a bad practices though the project is rather small. It would be better to categorize the functions and put them in a appropriate class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, there is. If you app's name were, for instance, "myApp", then you could call the global function, which has the same name and number of argument as the one in your class `B`, like so:

```
func b()
{
    print(myApp.a(100))   
}
```

Answer (score 6):

My suggestion is to keep your global functions in a class like this:

```
class Global {
   static func a(i: Int) -> Int {
      return i + 10
   }
}

class B {
   func a(s: String) -> String {
      return s + "bbb"
   }

   func b() {
      print(Global.a(100))
   }
}
```

This way, your code is more readable and is less confusing for compiler.